# Xcode support for C++

Tags: c++, xcode, makefile

I try to use Xcode (v.7.3.1) for my C++ project (build system - make), but the experience is quite poor (and it was always like that since old versions like v4 when I started using it) - code completion doesn't work, color syntaxing works oddly (no coloring sometimes, or partially colored code), no "jump-to-definition" functionality, can't switch b/w header/source files with shortcuts. Basically, it's just a text editor where I have to use "Find" and Cmd+Shift+O all the time.

Is this intentional and Xcode will never get any proper support for C++ projects with external build system (make) or am I misconfiguring my project? How can I re-index files in the project? How can I make code completion work?

Thanks,

Comment: Even Visual Studio 2015 sometimes has errors with code highlighting, often highlighting the `new/delete` keyword, then removing highlighting, and then partially highlighting it. It **IS** confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I ended up using this workaround: even though, I use external build system, I create **Console Application** project in Xcode and choose **C++ language** in settings. Then, I simply add my source files to the project (just drag folders from the Finder window) and then manually create project targets of type **External Build System** as I need. I don't use default target and don't use generated `main.cpp` file at all.

My files get indexed with no problems. I'm also able to debug code as I used to.

I still think Xcode developers should review indexing process for the projects with external build system...

Thanks for all the insights though!

Comment: As far as I know, Xcode never supported autocomplete with "External Build System" (or Makefiles, which are considered as an EBS by Xcode, it was just an alias in previous Xcode versions for pre-configuring the EBS target)

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a way to use Xcode with makefiles by adding an external build target, file->new->target->External Build System.

This is an older tutorial but the steps may be worth looking through: http://web.ist.utl.pt/jose.alberto.coelho/mac/MakefilesXcode.pdf

I've never had a problem with the syntax highlighting, but I remember the refactoring support being limited for C++ in some ways.

Comment: sure, external targets do work. what i'm saying is that functionality of modern IDE is not working. does "jump to definition" work for you in c++ (Cmd+Click on the function/method name)? Does code completion work?

Comment: Yeah jump to definition works for me and so does code completion. I'm on the prerelease Xcode 8 version so maybe that has something to do with it, but I think I remember those features working on past versions.

Comment: I'm thinking maybe it's because my header files are ".h", not ".hpp". What are yours?